# Как загрузить vue-forms-master/projects/create?

Tags: ajax, laravel, vue.js, openserver, axios

Прохожу курс по vue.js, и на каком-то этапе начались уроки по взаимодействию с бэкэндом. На github было предоставлено то, что проделывалось в уроке: https://github.com/laracasts/Vue-Forms. Хочу разобраться с тем, как загрузить vue-forms-master/projects/create, как это делалось в видео, но не понимаю как.
У меня установлен Open Server. В настройках во вкладке "Домены" установлен автопоиск.
Перейти по этому пути (vue-forms-master/projects/create) не могу - браузер выдаёт, что такой объект не найден. Зашла во http://vue-forms-master/resources/views/projects/create.blade.php, вот что получилось:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`@include('projects.list')` не считывается. Я не понимаю, почему и какие действия необходимо сделать. Также, когда нажимаю на кнопку "Create" - "Объект не найден!". В чём ошибка и что нужно изменить? Очень плохо знакома с Laravel и работой Open Server.

Настройки Open Server и ошибка в браузере:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На всякий случай:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема, как я понимаю, в том, что в папке vendor нет файла autoload.php, на который ссылается autoload.php в папке bootstrap
[image]

Также возникла какая-то ошибка и команда npm install также закончилась ошибкой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
AppServiceProvider.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }
}
```

Comment: Потому что Вы неправильно настроили директорию. В Laravel корневая папка должна быть `/public/`, от неё уже идут маршруты. Вызывать остальные файлы из папок уровня выше запрещено - это нарушение безопасности.

Comment: Для Laravel во вкладке "Домены" вручную установите домен с путем до этой папки (настройка ручное+автопоиск, как-то так называется)

Comment: @VladimirGonchar, я пробовала и так, также vue-forms-master/projects/create - не запускается и такие же проблемы с http://vue-forms-master/resources/views/projects/create.blade.php

Comment: Просто прописываете домен и идёте по адресу `/projects/create`...

Comment: @ТаняМальцева, добавьте скриншот с настройками опенсервера - настройки - домены.

Comment: @AlexZelenskiy, добавила. Также заметила, что в скаченной с github папке отсутствует autoload.php в папке vendor, попробовала добавить вручную: `<?php

// autoload.php @generated by Composer

require_once __DIR__ . '/composer/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInit369a13460ad584d9a5fc57078f92d753::getLoader();`. Но всё осталось без изменений.

Comment: @ТаняМальцева, не стоит трограть автолоад. Вопросы: 1)почему вы используете vue-forms-master если в доменах прописано vue-master; 2) что с маршрутами(php artisan route:list) - прописаны и открываются(главная страница http://vue-master и та, что ищете); 3) npm install && npm run dev - выполнялось?

Comment: @AlexZelenskiy, 1) потому что сначала в настройках был указан автопоиск - название проекта Vue-forms-master, а потом с ручным управлением я назвала домен - vue-master. По поводу остальных 2 вопросов - я предоставила скрин, на котором отображена ошибка - не получилось вывести php artisan route:list и не получилась команда npm install

Comment: @ТаняМальцева, пробуйте "composer update"

Comment: @AlexZelenskiy, также выдало ошибку и также не получилось после этого вызвать команду npm install без ошибки.

Comment: @ТаняМальцева, а Вы не думали создать новый проект, прописать домены в опенсервере, проверить что бы работало, настроить поновой маршруты, контроллеры etc?

Comment: @AlexZelenskiy, на самом деле думала, нужно попробовать, спасибо

Comment: @AlexZelenskiy, у меня появилась новая ошибка: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: select * from `projects`). Проблемы в файле .env? Я там ничего не меняла.

Comment: @AlexZelenskiy, попробовала установить default string в AppServiceProvider.php, но ничего не изменилось. Вставила код в вопрос.

Comment: @ТаняМальцева, SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'  - это значит, что у вас пытается подключится к базе данных пользователь рут и получает отказ от базы данных ( да - это нужно настраивать )

Comment: @AlexZelenskiy, хотелось бы задать ещё один вопрос по поводу проекта. Не знаю, предполагалось ли автором видео, работа с базой данных? Нужно ли мне создавать таблицу projects? С доступом к базе данных я вроде бы разобралась, теперь у меня появилась подобная проблема: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mysql.projects' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `projects`). Получается, что нужно создавать таблицу в базе данных?

Comment: @AlexZelenskiy, Видимо данный код в файле list.blade.php предполагает наличие данной таблицы: `@if (count($projects))
 <h1 class="title is-3">My Projects</h1>

 <ul>
  @foreach ($projects as $project)
   <li>
    <a href="#">{{ $project->name }}</a>
   </li>
  @endforeach
 </ul>` Правильно ли я понимаю?

Comment: @ТаняМальцева, Вы действительно хотите походя(уча фреймворк Vue) пройти еще и фреймворк Laravel? Личное мнение - стоит пересмотреть план на учебу. Учите одно, потом другое и потом - пытайтесь их скомпоновать. По поводу ваших вопросов: 1) при создании проекта - нужно создавать еще и БД(указываете в env файле имя базы, пользователя и пароль). 2) Если в blade шаблоне прописаны какие либо переменные, то их нужно откуда то брать либо закрывать дефолтными данными( в вашем случае $projects приходит как набор данных из контроллера - эти данные МОГУТ запрашиваться из БД)

Comment: @ТаняМальцева в блэйд шаблоне строится список из ссылок(предпологается что в шаблон поступают данные $projects)

Comment: @AlexZelenskiy, большое спасибо! Данная информация и ваше мнение были полезны для меня.